# How to fetch attribute values from Web.config XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have a web.config file and i want to retrieve the connection string value of particular key name.

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="abc" connectionString="Server=(local);Initial Catalog=abc;Integrated Security=SSPI;Max Pool Size=25" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="cde" connectionString="Server=(local);Initial Catalog=cde; Integrated Security=SSPI;Max Pool Size=50" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

I know i can fetch the connection string by configurationManager but i want to get that through XML reader. Presently i am using

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(fullPath);
var connectionString = from c in document.Descendants(connectionStrings)
select c ;
```

I am getting both the connection string. but i want to get specific "abc" connection string. can you please help me out.

Comment: Just curious, why you need to use LINQ to XML, meanwhile ConfigurationManager supports simply?

Comment: actually i want to fetch the connection string from the web.config which is not in the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(fullPath);
var connectionString = from c in document.Descendants("connectionStrings").Descendants("add")
    where c.Attribute("name").Value == "abc"                
    select c;
```

Comment: am receiving error. object reference not set to instance of object

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (using a little fluent syntax)

```
var connectionString = document.Descendants("connectionStrings")
                       .Descendants("add")
                       .First(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "abc").Attribute("connectionString").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load(fullPath);
var connectionString = from c in document.Descendants("connectionStrings")
                       where c.name=="abc"               
                       select c ;
```

Comment: Firstly from where this c.name will come ? as it will not know the property